# C++ - Why i can't use int*p=&arr (arr refers to an array) to init a pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, ram

I made a pointer called `*p` and init with `arr` and output the result of `arr` and `&arr`;

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int arr[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    cout<<arr<<endl;
    cout<<&arr<<endl;
    int *p=arr;
    cout<<p<<endl;
}
```

I ran it, everything is working fine and have output likes this

```
0xfe0dff5d0
0xfe0dff5d0
0xfe0dff5d0
```

l found that `cout<<arr<<endl` and `cout<<&arr<<endl` both show the same answer as `0xfe0dff5d0`

In some turotorials of C++, i noted that to use pointer to control a array should be like `int *p=arr // arr refers to an array`. But i found that `arr` and `&arr` gives the same output, so i began to try to use `&arr` to init a pointer to access to an array. And i failed with error like this:

```cpp
ptr-array.cpp:9:13: error: cannot convert 'int (*)[9]' to 'int*' in initialization
    9 |     int *p2=&arr;
      |             ^~~~
      |             |
      |             int (*)[9]
```

I'm puzzled with why `arr` and `&arr` gives the same output, but i can't init a pointer with `&arr`.

---

###### In addition:

As the comment under this question, i aslo found that `&arr[0]` aslo can init a pointer to access a array.

**In short: i'm puzzled with why i can't init a pointer with `&arr` but init a pointer with `arr` and `&arr[0]` though all of them direct to the same address in RAM**

Comment: Can't you use &arr[0] ? Calling &arr seems wrong since the array is already a pointer. Cout is probably just fixing stuff for you when you passed &arr.

Comment: @Adriel Jr Thanks for reply, you suggetions works well, but i just what to know why `arr`, `&arr`, `&arr[0] (as you comment)` all of them direct to the same RAM address, but i can't init the pointer with `&arr` and others can.

Comment: `arr` and `&arr` might have the same value, but the _types_ are different. The error you see is the type mismatch error.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` - please don't do this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: @AdrielJr An array is not a pointer. That's just an unfortunate illusion.

Comment: `&arr` and `&arr[0]` have the same value (in the sense that converting them to `void *` which is what happens when you stream them to `cout`) but they have different *type* -  `&arr` has type `int (*)[9]` i.e. it is a pointer to an array of 9 elements, while `&arr[0]` is of type `int *`. To initialise an `int *`, the initialiser must be either of type `int *` or *implicitly convertible* to an `int *`. `arr` (the name of the array) CAN be implicitly converted to an `int *`, equal to `&arr[0]` (the "array to pointer conversion") but `&arr` (of type `int (*)[9]`) cannot be.